# how to disable/enable all elements in an html table using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a table with 2 inputs in each rows, all binded to a `self.editing = ko.computed(…)`, i.e., for each single element in the table I have to 
`<input type="number" data-bind="textInput:myObservObj, enable: editing" />`

how can I avoid this and have something else that can accept an observable object in this case editing and enable/disable all inputs in the table?

here is my full html code (as you can see I have to repeat `enable: $parent.editing` everywhere):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:115px"></td>
      <td style="margin-right: 10px">Left</td>
      <td>Right</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Type (Jerger)</label></td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="with:leftEarTympanometry">
                    <select data-bind="options: availableTypes,
                       value: type,
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose...', enable: $parent.editing, style: { borderColor: 'black' }"></select>
                </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="with:rightEarTympanometry">
                    <select data-bind="options: availableTypes,
                       value: type,
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose...', enable: $parent.editing, style: { borderColor: 'black' }"></select>
                </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Pressure (daPa)</label></td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="with:leftEarTympanometry">
                    <input type="number" data-bind="textInput:pressure, enable: $parent.editing, style: { borderColor: pressureInvalid() ? 'red' : 'black' }"/>
                </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="with:rightEarTympanometry">
                    <input type="number" data-bind="textInput:pressure, enable: $parent.editing, style: { borderColor: pressureInvalid()? 'red' : 'black' }"/>
                </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Peak (mmho)</label></td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="with:leftEarTympanometry">
                    <input type="number" data-bind="textInput:peak, enable: $parent.editing, style: { borderColor: peakInvalid()? 'red' : 'black' }"/>
                </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="with:rightEarTympanometry">
                    <input type="number" data-bind="textInput:peak, enable: $parent.editing, style: { borderColor: peakInvalid()? 'red' : 'black' }" />
                </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Volume (cc)</label></td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="with:leftEarTympanometry">
                    <input type="number" data-bind="textInput:volume, enable: $parent.editing, style: { borderColor: volumeInvalid()? 'red' : 'black' }"/>
                </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="with:rightEarTympanometry">
                    <input type="number" data-bind="textInput:volume, enable: $parent.editing, style: { borderColor: volumeInvalid()? 'red' : 'black' }"/>
                </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Give us the computed definition! In essence all you have to do is either:
a) Use the same observable for all rows, instead of having each row with its self.editing property, have a new one on the parent viewmodel and use $parent.editing on all data-bound inputs
b) If the definition contains must also contain a property for each row ill make an answer when you provide the computed definition

Comment: in my opinion i will assign a property in my `myObservObj` something like myObservObj.isEnable = ko.observalbe(false) //default is false. So when you raise an event call bind this to `true` then binding will make it enable or not

Comment: @HuaTrung currently I have to repeat this thing for each row in the table I'm sharing my whole code here so you can see it better

Comment: in my code, i use the way like your coding. if u dont want to code each element like above, i think there is a way to do that with custom bindinghandler like this:
`<input type="number" data-bind="inputEnable:volume, style: { borderColor: volumeInvalid()? 'red' : 'black' }"/>` and in your custom bindinghandler you write your own logic. here is sample example with Jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/huatrung102/7dangvL2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom binding, like this one:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.enableAll = {
        update: function(elem, valueAccessor) {
            var enabled = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(elem.getElementsByTagName('input'), function(i) {
                i.disabled = !enabled;
            });
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(elem.getElementsByTagName('select'), function(i) {
                i.disabled = !enabled;
            });
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(elem.getElementsByTagName('checkbox'), function(i) {
                i.disabled = !enabled;
            });
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(elem.getElementsByTagName('textarea'), function(i) {
                i.disabled = !enabled;
            });

        }
    };
```

and then on your form, just bind enableAll to true or false depending on if you want to disable all controls or enable all of them, something like:

```
<form data-bind="enableAll: somecondition()">
     ...
</form>
```